# Need help with Maclaurin Series for $\cos^2 x$

Tags: sequences-and-series

So I have been working on finding the Maclaurin series for $\cos^2 x$

I am thinking of using the identity: $\cos^2 x = {1\over 2}(1+\cos(2x))$

By using the known Maclaurin series for $cos(x)$, I found the Maclaurin series for $\displaystyle \cos(2x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n {(2x)^{2n}\over (2n)!}$

So, I have the Maclaurin series for $\cos(2x)$, but I am confused on how to incorporate the whole function, ${1\over 2}(1+\cos(2x))$ into a summation notation. Can someone please show or explain the beginning steps on how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have done it all.  You had reached 
$$\cos(2x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{2^{2n}}{(2n)!}x^{2n}.$$
Now we look at $\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos(2x))$. It is convenient to separate out the first term, which is $1$. We then get the series
$$1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{2^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}x^{2n}.$$

Comment: Note that you get a "two-fer" out of this, since $ \ \sin^2 x = 1 - \cos^2 x \ $ , so  $$\sin^2 x = \ 1 \ - \ \left[1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{2^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}x^{2n} \right] \ = \ - \  \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{2^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}x^{2n} \ = \ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{2^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}x^{2n} \ \ . $$  This is reasonable because both $ \ \cos^2 x \ $ and $ \ \sin^2 x \ $ are even functions.